# Alegbra Equation to solve client's request

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A client of mine gave me an equation to solve withholding taxes and etc. This is what he gave me: 
$$A = \frac{B}{(P + B) / 1.12}$$
I do not see how to rearrange this into the form of $B=\ldots$. It seems particularly difficult as there are multiple $B$'s on the left hand side.

Comment: Hard to tell if that $1.12$ is dividing $\frac{B}{(P+B)}$ or $(P+B)$.

Comment: I saw an informational video last week something about this equation **3 / 1 / 3 + 1** and it said that the common mistake of many is that they answered **2** but the correct answer is **10**. It said that you will first reciprocate **1/3**

Comment: So we have $A= \frac{1.12\cdot B}{P+B}$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$A= \frac{1.12\cdot B}{P+B}$$

we may multiply both sides by $(P+B)$ to obtain $$AP+AB=1.12\cdot B$$ which we rearrange to $$AP=B\cdot(1.12-A)$$

Finally, dividing by $(1.12-A)$ yields $$B=\frac{AP}{1.12-A}$$

Or if you prefer integer coefficients,

$$B = \frac{25AP}{28-25A}$$

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome.